# Убрать анимацию нажатия

Tags: java, android

Как можно убрать анимацию нажатия на элементы listview?
чтобы они не выделялись при нажатии

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Добавьте в разметку `ListView` эту строчку `android:listSelector="@android:color/transparent"`